# Power failure and digital clocks

Tags: power, clock-speed

I'm asking this here in the interest of figuring out why this happened, and how to fix it. Feel free to suggest different tags, or a different stack. That said...

The power went out the other day. No idea why. Anything sensitive  (smart TV, game console, computers) we on surge protectors, and they were all fine. However, the cheap coffee pot (has a clock, and a timed brewing) is now running fast. We set the clock this morning about 7am, and now its about 3 hours fast.

What about a power outage, possible surge, could cause a digital clock to start running fast? The coffee clock was perfect before the power loss.

If needed, there was a smart TV on, and a PS3 on when the power went out, as well as some lights and an alarm clock. The alarm clock is fine, it has no surge protector nor does the coffee clock.

**Edit**

I'm going to try "power cycling" the coffee pot. Unplug for an hour, and see if that helps. ... this is a weird problem I've never seen in commercial clocks before.

**Edit 2**
About to plug the coffee pot back in. I'll set the time correct now (about 2334), and will update in the morning if it's keeping correct time.

**Final Edit**
So I power cycled the coffee pot, and now it's keeping correct time. I'm not sure what happened to make it run fast, but now it's working fine.

I'm not sure if I should leave this question here, since on the one hand, there really isn't a real answer, yet on the other hand, the existing answers do still provide some interesting information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities.

1. Since you're apparently in a 60Hz region, if the clock counts power-line
   cycles it would need to know if the mains frequency was 50Hz or 60Hz. 
   If it thinks it is 50Hz but it actually is 60Hz then it would run fast by
   exactly 20%. You don't say how long it's been running (I don't know your
   time zone)but that would imply about 15 hours running, which is possible. If that setting has been corrupted by an ugly power cycle (and cheap supervisory circuitry and dubious programming) then it could default to 50Hz, which is the most common setting worldwide.
2. If it has a power backup RC clock (low accuracy) that is intended to keep the clock reasonably close to being on for a short failure under battery or super-capacitor backup power, and the
   surge zapped the mains clock circuit (quite plausible) then it would
   run on the RC clock continuously, which could be 5% or 10% or 20% fast or slow (or anywhere inbetween). So if the power blipped off for 10 minutes the clock would be correct within a minute or two.

In the latter case, the clock functionality is probably toast. In the former case, you might be able to find a secret setup EEPROM variable triggered by something like holding keys down as the unit is powered up or something like that. Good luck without instructions, but maybe there is info available somewhere.

For anyone actually doing this kind of design, this answer points out a couple of things **not** to do.

1. Don't depend on dubious circuitry to protect against mains surges
2. Don't use simple RC reset circuits when EEPROM corruption can cause problems. Enough units in the field and you will regret it.

Comment: We reset it about 7am this morning. Time is now 2249, and it's reading 0137. We are in the southwestern US. I'm not sure of the hertz here, but I think I read somewhere all of the US is on 60 Htz? (Times are approximately within 5 minutes)

Comment: Definitely 60Hz in the continental US. That seems like more than 20% fast.

Comment: Do try the power cycle, if you have not already. It is possible bad programming could cause such a problem (variable in RAM initialized only at start-up)

Comment: these devices often use the LM8650 alarm clock IC which counts AC cycles,  this ASIC is not programmable in any way (other than setting the time, sleep counter, and alarm registers) 50/60Hz is set by an external jumper.